# Webpack dev server not recompiling when files change

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a project that's broken into 3 parts: a server and two webpack bundled web clients (App and Admin). The two web clients use basically the same webpack config with slight changes for setting output directories and dev server ports. Each client has its own `package.json` with a `watch` script that just runs `webpack-dev-server`.

The `watch` script on both clients succeed: the app builds and is accessible in a web browser. However, one of the clients (the Admin site) doesn't ever rebuild when changes are made, and seems to be constantly using an old build (`webpack-dev-server` hosts an old build even after restarting). The other client rebuilds fine.

What is happening here? They're configured almost exactly the same, they use the same plugins/loaders/etc, they're using similar libraries (React, mobx, etc).

Here's the base webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('lodash');
const loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const env = process.env['NODE_ENV'];
const clientsRootDir = __dirname;

const defaultConfig = {
  buildDir: 'dist',
  entry: 'src/entry.js',
  server: 'http://localhost:8000',
  devServerPort: 8080,
  constants: {
    NODE_ENV: env,
    PRODUCTION: env === 'production',
    DEVELOPMENT: env === 'development',
    DEBUG: env === 'development',
    TEST: env === 'test',
    LOG_LEVEL: env === 'production' ? 'error' : 'debug'
  },
  globalModules: {
    React: 'react',
    log: 'shared/log',
  },
};

module.exports = (config) => {
  config = merge({}, defaultConfig, config);
  const { rootDir } = config;
  const local = file => path.resolve(rootDir, file);

  return {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: local(config.entry),
    output: {
      path: local(config.buildDir),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: [
        'node_modules',
        local('src'),
        path.join(clientsRootDir, 'Shared')
      ],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
        {test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$/, use: [
          {loader: 'file-loader'},
        ]},
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: [
              {loader: 'css-loader', options: {
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName: '[path]_[local]',
              }},
              {loader: 'sass-loader'},
              {loader: 'postcss-loader'},
            ],
          }),
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', { allChunks: true }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin(config.globalModules),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(config.constants),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './src/index.html',
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      port: config.devServerPort,
      proxy: {
        '/api': config.server
      },
    },
  };
};
```

The working App `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = require('../webpack.base.config')(Object.assign(
  {rootDir: __dirname},
  require('./config'),
));
```

And the app config:

```
module.exports = {
  appId: 'com.company.app',
  server: 'http://localhost:8000',
  buildDir: 'www',
  devServerPort: 8080,
};
```

The broken Admin `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = require('../webpack.base.config')(Object.assign(
  {rootDir: __dirname},
  require('./config'),
));
```

And the admin config:

```
module.exports = {
  appId: 'com.company.app_admin',
  server: 'http://localhost:8000',
  buildDir: '../../Server/public/admin',
  devServerPort: 8081,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being some kind of folder renaming issue. I had moved the entire project and re-cloned while I had an iterm session open in the Admin folder. Either iterm or zshell got confused because `pwd` showed the correct path, but the branch zshell was displaying was incorrect. Running `cd .` corrected the branch zshell was displaying, and the `watch` script works fine now.

So the real issue was I was running watch in the wrong project even though my shell was telling me I was in the right project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and SimpleJ's answer seems to have given me the hint I needed. I had a file `SomeFolder/someFile.js`, but it was being imported as `../somefolder/somefile` (all lowercase).

Changing the capitalization in the `import` statement to match that of the actual folder and file seems to have remedied the issue.